# Jquery Graph sort by date does'nt work properly

Tags: php, graph, foreach, google-analytics-api

I want to display data in my graph. 
My data are from a foreach : Visits per date.
The problem is that when I display the date, it doesn't work properly. My graph axe x doesn't take in consideration the month.

It's displaying like :

> 1 Feb, 2 Feb, 3 Feb, 25 Jan, 26 Jan, 27 Jan, 28 Jan, 29 Jan, 30 Jan,
>   31 Jan

But I want :

> 25 Jan, 26 Jan, 27 Jan, 28 Jan, 29 Jan, 30 Jan, 31 Jan, 1 Feb, 2 Feb,
>   3 Feb

Knowing that when I echo my foreach, I have it in the right order:

My code:

```
<?php 
$ga->requestReportData($profileId,array('date'),array('visitors'), '-date'); 
?>

$(function () {
// Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'graph-area',
        padding: 10,
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        gridEnabled: false,
        gridLineColor: '#dddddd',
        axes: false,
        fillOpacity:.7,
        data: [<?php

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
    echo "{period: '".date('j-M-Y',strtotime($result->getDate()))."', Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},\n";}     


?>],
        lineColors:['#E67A77','#79D1CF','#79D1CF'],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['Visites'],
        labels: ['Visites'],
        pointSize: 4,
        lineWidth: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });
});
```